# Return array from function in Nodejs and send it to ejs view?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Okay, so my code is pulling data from a yelp business using their official API. My problem is that I can't seem to get the data to return out of the function. The problem isn't in ejs, it's that the data doesn't return when I tell it to! I just get undefined with some attempts, and with others (including the one I'm going to show here), I get an empty array. I'm pasting only the code that's important, let me know if you need more!

```
 function yelp(){

  var b = [];
  var i = 0;
 (struck the initialization of client)
client.business("(struck)", function(error, data) {
      if (error != undefined){
        res.send("an error occured. exiting");
        process.process.reallyExit();
      }
      b[i++] = data.name;
      b[i++] = data.display_phone;
      b[i++] = data.rating;
      console.log(b); //NEW!!
    });
    console.log(b);
    return b;
}

app.get('/yelp', function(req,res){
     var arr = yelp();
     console.log(arr);
     res.render('yelp.ejs', {title: 'Yelp!', arr: arr});   
  });
}
```

I added one more line of code, that I THINK may have narrowed down the problem to being related to my poor internet connection. I added ANOTHER console.log(b), this time inside of the business API call. the console.log(arr) is shows second, the console.log(b); just before the reutrn shows first, and LAST is the console.log(b) INSIDE the API call. It also took a good 30 seconds for that log to appear, and it appeared AFTER the page loaded. So, how do I go about making the page wait for the data? Or is this unrelated to my problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nodejs is async, meaning the app won't wait for the yelp() function to return. you can pass the yelp function a callback like so:

```
 function yelp(callback){

  var b = [];
  var i = 0;
 (struck the initialization of client)
client.business("(struck)", function(error, data) {
      if (error != undefined){
        res.send("an error occured. exiting");
        process.process.reallyExit();
      }
      b[i++] = data.name;
      b[i++] = data.display_phone;
      b[i++] = data.rating;
    });
    console.log(b);
    callback(b);
}
yelp(funtion(arr) {
 res.render('yelp.ejs', {title: 'Yelp!', arr: arr});   
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing their API, I do recognize the callback style. The result of the call to your client would then be in the `data` parameter in the callback, and thats where you want to render your view.

The following is not tested.

```
function yelp(cb) {
    var b = [];
    var i = 0;
    // (struck the initialization of client)
    client.business("(struck)", function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            return cb(error);
        }
        b[i++] = data.name;
        b[i++] = data.display_phone;
        b[i++] = data.rating;
    });
    console.log(b);
    cb(null, b)
}

app.get('/yelp', function(req, res) {
    yelp(function(err, arr) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("an error occured. exiting");
            process.process.reallyExit();
            return;
        }
        console.log(arr);
        res.render('yelp.ejs', {
            title: 'Yelp!',
            arr: arr
        });
    });

});
```

The thing to notice here, is the callback passing. This is normally how you do
async work in Node.js. It can be made a bit prettier using [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting sync things to happen, but it's async.  Your `client.business` method takes in a callback as it's second argument which isn't returning by the time `res.render` gets called.

Try this:

```
function yelp(callback) {

  var b = [];
  var i = 0;

  client.business("(struck)", function(error, data) {
    if (error != undefined){
      res.send("an error occured. exiting");
      process.process.reallyExit();
    }
    b[i++] = data.name;
    b[i++] = data.display_phone;
    b[i++] = data.rating;

    // No returns in async.  Just call the callback.
    callback('yelp.ejs', { {title: 'Yelp!', arr: b}})

  });

}

app.get('/yelp', function(req,res){
  yelp(res.render);
});
```